# how to sort list has object type add two classes objects then both class has conman fields age

Tags: java

```
 List<Object> melist = new ArrayList<Object>();    
 melist.add(new Emp(1, "Joy", 25));    
 melist.add(new Student(4, "pradeep", 26));    
 melist.add(new Emp(2, "RK", 26));   
 melist.add(new Emp(3, "Sumit", 22));   
 melist.add(new Student(5, "Roy", 56));
```

i want to sort list by age   and age is field in both class emp    and Studentsi

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please rephrase your question and format your text properly. It is very hard to read.

Comment: Take a look at `Collections.sort()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29

Answer (score 1):

Implement a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your class `Emp` and then use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)) to sort your list.

```
class EmpComparator implements Comparator<Emp> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Emp o1, Emp o2) {
        return o1.getAge().compareTo(o2.getAge());
    }
}
```

Then use the `Comparator` as

```
Collections.sort(melist, new EmpComparator());
```

Comment: but i have Emp and Students Class how

Comment: Do they share a common base class or interface (such as ``Person``)? You can implement a ``Comparator`` for that class then.